# Folder Sizes in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Back when i was using xp i had this program called [Folder Sizes](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/) 
that showed the folder(also file) size in the explorer column
 
I was wondering will that option be or is available in nautilus or other file-manager

[image]

<sup>Screenshot</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. (*Disclaimer: all this methods can only make the folders show the amount of items that they contain, not their actual size*)

Probabliy the most used option is to use the "List View" mode. You can enable it by going to `View` menu and click on `List`. You get this:
[image]

But there's also a really comfortable method to do it, which allows you to navigate your folders  using the "Icons View". All you have to do is going to `Edit` menu, click on `Preferences` option and then click on the `Display` tab. After that you have to set the first zooming option to show you the size of your folders and files.
[image]
[image]

Comment: in your screen-shot you see a "nautilus Scripts" folder what i want is to see the "5 items" comment to state the KB/MB/GB? size of that folder. completely remove the "5 items" comment(and also if nautilus can't do that is there another file-manager that can show folder sizes)

Comment: I'm afraid of not finding a file manager that can do what you want: Thunar (from the XFCE Project) show the size of the folders, but it shows 4,0 KB for every folder, Marlin (from the elementary Project) does exactly the same. Dolphin (from KDE) used to show the size (http://imagenes.es.sftcdn.net/es/scrn/58000/58377/dolphin-file-manager-19.jpg) but now it does not (http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_oFB9sXQiV5Q/TBJGioxdkKI/AAAAAAAAHCc/SMKkqg5Z7z0/s1600/Dolphin.jpg) and behaves like Nautilus.

Comment: thats too bad :( but thanks for the effort anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplish thru menu>system tools>diskanalyzer  aka baobab

You just select the desired folder and it displays the sizes of all contained folders and files both as a summary and as a list of folder with sizes.

Not sure if it installs directly with Ubuntu, but it's on my install of 12.04

Answer (score -2):

In Nautilus, go to "View" Menu and click on "List"

Comment: that doesn't show the sizes just the number of items in the folder.